# I can't set up the following Netsh settings, because the object is already exist

Tags: windows-7, networking, routing, ipv6, windows-server-2012

I use the `Netsh int ipv6 show int` in terminal, the result:

```
1   50   4294967295   connected   Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
11  10         1500   connected   Local connection
```

When I wanted to use the followings tasks:

```
Netsh interface ipv6 set interface 11 advertise=enabled
Netsh interface ipv6 add route 1024::/64 11 publish=yes
Netsh interface ipv6 add route fda8:06c3:ce53:a890::/64 11 publish=yes*
```

And when I tried the 3. line, written is *the object is already exist.* That is why I can't run this task. How can I set these settings?

[image]

Comment: Have you opened the terminal window as administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The 3rd command is trying to add a route with specific settings.
2. The route already exists.

Given that, the obvious option would be to *change the existing route* to use the same specific settings. Use `netsh interface ipv6 set route ... publish=yes` to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
function set-ip-static ([string]$ip, [string]$strMask, [string]$gateway, [string]$dns1, [string]$dns2, [string]$networkInterface)  {
    netsh interface ipv4 set address name=$networkInterface static $ip $strMask $gateway  1
    netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsservers name=$networkInterface all validate=no
    netsh interface ipv4 set dns name=$networkInterface static addr=$dns1 validate=no
    netsh interface ipv4 add dnsservers name=$networkInterface addr=$dns2 index=2 validate=no
}

function set-ip-whatever {
    $ip = "192.168.201.25"
    $strMask = "255.255.255.0"
    $gateway = "192.168.201.254"
    $dns1 = "8.8.8.8"
    $dns2 = "8.8.4.4"
    $networkInterface = "Wi-Fi 2"
    set-ip-static $ip $strMask $gateway $dns1 $dns2 $networkInterface
}
```

Comment: If you're going to write PowerShell, why not write it _all_ in PowerShell?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I tried to, but got the object already exists error. Using netsh was my solution. Edit: Tried for a really long time too and gave up. Happy with this. Works exactly how I expect it to.  Also, could be easily translated to a batch file or whatever, but I'm trying to get familiar with Powershell so this is what I ended up with.